# Simple D program Output order is wrong

Tags: d

I am learning a new language called "D" but i have a problem when trying to write a simple program

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    double gradeOne;
    writeln("Please enter the First Test Grade: ");
    readf(" s", &gradeOne);


}
```

Why does my program ask me for the input first before the output message?

I think its just the DDT problem, when i run the program in command prompt its working fine

Comment: hmm it works for me, what operating system are you on? Maybe it is buffering the output too long.

Comment: BTW the readf should say"%s", not " s"

Comment: what happens when you flush between the writeln and readf

Comment: I am using D Development Tool for Eclipse, for some reason the out put box in eclipse is acting weird the program asks for all the inputs first.

Comment: I am having serious problems with DDT and Eclipse as well. It's to the point where testing has to be done outside of Eclipse if there's any communication between apps, or if they take user input. At first I thought one program in Eclipse would simply block the next one I tried to run, but it may indeed be that the input and output streams are never flushed in the Eclipse console. It's very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output to Eclipse buffers output by larger data blocks rather than lines. To force output to appear, insert calls to `stdout.flush();` before asking for input to ensure it shows up when you want it.

See also: [Eclipse console writes output only after the program has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498040/eclipse-console-writes-output-only-after-the-program-has-finished/19498469#19498469)

Comment: thanks, its been a longtime but i finally remember to give u the check for right answer!