# Eclipse console writes output only after the program has finished

Tags: eclipse, console, d

I have the following D program:

```
void main( string[] args )
{
    import core.thread, std.stdio;

    for ( int i = 10; i > 0; --i )
    {
        writeln( i );
        Thread.sleep(dur!"seconds"(1) );
    }
    writeln("Bang!");
}
```

It counts from 10 down to 1 and then outputs `"Bang!"`. Between each output the program waits for the duration of one second. When I run this program in Eclipse (Eclipse Platform, Version: 3.8.1, Build id: debbuild) with the DDT plugin (Version: 0.8.1.v201309231) then the console output is as expected, but it apppears only until after the program has finished running.

When I start the same program from the console, then the program behaves as it should.

How can I fix that?

Comment: try putting stdout.flush(); before the sleep. not sure if eclipse will flush too, but worth a try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put stdout.flush() before the sleep line. stdout is buffered, so flush ensures it actually gets out to the device instead of waiting in the buffer.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's going on here, but I think the line buffering only happens if the receiving end is a regular terminal. Otherwise, it gets the same buffering as any other file (because it likely *is* any other file). With Eclipse, again I'm guessing, it is probably talking to the eclipse process through a pipe, and that isn't registering as an interactive terminal so it goes back to full buffering.

Comment: I've opened an enhancement request for this: https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13778